# Test tsql inserts before doing actual inserts?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an asp.net application that inserts to several tsql tables. The format is the following:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.InsertNewCar(); //Makes SP call usp_InsertCar()

Truck myTruck = new Truck();
myTruck.InsertNewTruck(); //Makes SP call usp_InsertTruck()

Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
myCustomer.InsertNewCustomers(); //Makes SP call usp_InsertCustomers()
```

Each of these methods have a try...catch exception. The problem is that it may break in `myCustomer.InsertNewCustomers()`, but the 2 previous inserts have been completed. I then have to manually delete all inserts and then try again. We already do data check, but this still happens.

I was considering using COMMIT & ROLLBACK with each of these stored procedures, so the first pass would call all 5 methods that would rollback the transaction. If everything was OK, then I'd call the same stored procedures with a COMMIT. That way I can be certain that the inserts will be made correctly.

Would that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  You would want to wrap a transaction around all these calls so they all occur in a single transaction.

Comment: Adding on to what @GordonLinoff was saying, you can use `TransactionScope` around all of the calls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And what if it doesn't come out OK? (underlying question, why do a rollback at second commit at all? Is just wrapping in a transaction and commit on success/rollback on failure sufficient?)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I wrap all these stored procedure calls in 1 transaction? I was thinking of adding `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` to each stored procedure. Can I wrap all stored procedures around only 1?

Comment: The major problem of your approach is: if you know all five sprocs finish successfully, how do you know for certain that when you run your sprocs again, nothing happened in the meantime that will cause them to fail?

Comment: You're right. I wasn't aware that there existed a `TransactionScope` Class for exactly these situations.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing now is that I can only use `TransactionScope` if I call the stored procedures through `SqlCommand`. But methods `InsertToTable1()` to `InsertToTable5()` have more code than just the SP calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the transactions from your C# code. Add a `using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())` block to wrap your calls. I think you might need to use the same connection for this though - so you could have to pass the connection object as a parameter to your methods.

**Edit:** Just to add some more detail....

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Assuming you are using SQL Server....
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
    {
        conn.Open();

        InsertToTable1(conn);
        // Snip...
        InsertToTable5(conn);

        // If this point is reached, everything is tickety boo            
        // Commit the transaction using Complete.
        // If the scope.Complete line is not hit before the using block 
        // is exited (i.e. an Exception is thrown, the transaction is rolled               
        // back.
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Your `InsertIntoTable` methods would then  look something like

```
public void InsertIntoTable1(SqlConnection conn)
{
     //  Some non-database code could be here....

     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     // Configure command and execute

     //  Some non-database code could also be here....

}
```

Comment: The problem I'm seeing now is that I can only use `TransactionScope` if I call the stored procedures through `SqlCommand`. But methods `InsertToTable1()` to `InsertToTable5()` have more code than just the SP calls.

Comment: Without seeing the extra calls it's hard to make any suggestions, but non-CRUD code shouldn't be an issue. I'll throw a quick example into my answer but if you could give some background on the other code it might help me or others be a bit more precise.

Comment: They're non-CRUD, but they need to be done. And it's not the actual code that's the issue. It's that all these calls being made before the actual transaction would need to be moved to fit this.

Comment: I changed the code snippet in my question to make it more _realistic_. But I can't join all those SP calls into one.

Comment: So you're saying that it doesn't have to be called directly; I just need to use the same `SqlConnection`. I'll check and let you know, thanks.

Comment: As an aside, it looks, going on the edits you made to the OP, that your entities are responsible for their own persistence? `eg. myCar.InsertNewCar();`  I'd be inclined to separate my entities from my persistence code - this will allow the flexibility to swap database providers or ORMs in and out freely.

Comment: I added that code just to clarify that there are several different entities  that couldn't be combined into one call. I ended up using `TransactionScope` but I noticed that I don't even have to use the same `SqlConnection`. If a transaction fails within `TransactionScope`, everything is rolled back. In my case it's within a `Try..Catch`, so when a transaction fails, it rolls back and then jumps to the `Catch`

Comment: Glad you got it working. And thanks for clarifying re: the connection.. it's not a use case I've ever encountered so I'm learning here too. Best of luck from here on in.